# Automatic scrolling of UICollectionView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have got a `UICollectionView` with Single Row, and every cell has a different `width`, ( depending upon certain criteria ). Each `cell` has a `float timeInSeconds` property associated with it.

I want to automatic scroll the `UICollectionView` horizontally such a way that the the cell should pass in the `timeInSeconds` associated with that cell respectively.

I tried doing this using `NSTimer` and changing `contentOffset` but not working as I want.

Code:

```
//this method is called which fires the `NSTimer`
 - (void)configAutoscrollTimer {
    w = self.messagesCollectionView.contentOffset.x;

    autoScrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

 - (void)onTimer {
    [self autoScrollView];
}

 - (void)autoScrollView {

  NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_currentPlayIndex inSection:0];
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_messagesCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];


  w += ([(NSNumber*)_messagesArray[lastIndexPath.row][@"duration"] floatValue])/cell.bounds.size.width;

  CGPoint offsetPoint = CGPointMake(w, 0);
  self.messagesCollectionView.contentOffset = offsetPoint;
}
```

Screenshot of my horizontal view: 
[image]

I believe the problem is with `X` offset calculation, as to how many steps should it move according some formula. My formula failed :(

**Please guide as to how to achieve the auto scrolling according to the time associated with the cell. Thanks!**

Comment: Try to print the `w` value after you increment it and see if it increases accordingly.

Comment: @Sebyddd Done that already, It does increase, but the scrolling is not according the time of the `cell`. Like if the `cell` in question has 4 seconds associated with it, then the cell should pass the screen in 4 seconds. But this is not happening. scrolling is very slow.

Comment: What exactly happens when you change the offset? Does the scroll position change or it stays in the same place?

Comment: It scrolls at a fixed speed.. I want it to scroll according to the time associated with the current visible first `cell` .. That's why I tried to calculate the offset to move by dividing the `float time` value by `cell` width .. But not helping :(

Comment: Considering I don't know the values you're calculating. Are you sure the calculations are correct? The timer is firing every 0.01s, which is constant, so my bet is that the X offset calculation is not correct.

Comment: Exactly, That's the problem I know. Thats why I posted the question as to get help on calculating the `X` offset. I should add it in the question though.

Comment: I don't understand the correct behavior you want. I see in the image you have 3 cells (TK, SA, HA). For example, TK should move from right to left in 3 seconds, SA in 1 second and HA in 2 seconds? so cells could be put one over each other? or the scroll velocity of your collection view is constant? anyway "duration" is expressed in seconds, milliseconds, or what? please, enhance your question, it's not clear the issue and the desired behavior

Comment: @ddb the scroll velocity is constant right now.. I don't want it to be constant. It should vary depending on the cell's duration to pass. I hope it's clear?

Answer (score 0):

in physics, `space = velocity * time`, so `w` should be incremented by `velocity * time` (delta time for each 0.01 seconds).
If the visibile duration time of a cell is saved in `_messagesArray[lastIndexPath.row][@"duration"]`, you should be able to calculate `velocity` as `space/time`.
So, the increment should be defined like this

```
float v = self.messagesCollectionView.frame.size.width / ([(NSNumber*)_messagesArray[lastIndexPath.row][@"duration"] floatValue]);
w += v * 0.01f;
```

(of course `v` should be calculated only one time per cell)

let me know if it works or my answer should be edited

**EDIT**

velocity based on current cell width

```
float v = cell.bounds.size.width / ([(NSNumber*)_messagesArray[lastIndexPath.row][@"duration"] floatValue]);
w += v * 0.01f;
```

Comment: Tried it. It start slow but gradually increases the velocity. In short not working. But thanks for the effort man. Appreciate. Still figuring out how to solve this :S

Comment: @Sha, if collectionView width is constant (as I think), the velocity will change based on the "duration" value you have for the cell. Does the velocity remain constant for each cell? or it changes within the same cell?

Comment: Actually the velocity does change for different cells, like it gets slow and fast accordingly, but not working accurate, before the sound finishes, the entire collectionview has scrolled out of screen :(

Comment: So maybe the problem is that the velocity should be related to cell width rather than collectionView width, I'll update my answer

Comment: Tried but still not scrolling properly :(

Comment: What's the resulting behavior? Can you share a video?

Comment: please check http://gph.is/2alFHK2 

P.S. The circular ring provided a help as to when the cell should pass. The cell should pass as circular ring completes, in sync with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118621/discussion-between-ddb-and-sha).

Comment: @Sha, let's continua in [chat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652412/automatic-scrolling-of-uicollectionview-ios/38653336#)